# How to use the partition of Ubuntu when I have win 7

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning

I have Ubuntu and Windows to run in the past. Windows has broken, so I have to reinstall Windows. I have 2 partitions for Ubuntu that I have installed. I've just installed Windows 7 into the rest of partitions. Now, I can't choose Ubuntu to run as usual and I can't see the name of 2 partitions for Ubuntu, but I think it still has data. Can anyone help me recovery these partitions or data of them and run Ubuntu? Thanks very much. 2 partitions write Healthy(primary partition)

Comment: If the partitions are still there, most likely you simply need to reinstall the boot loader (which is almost certainly GRUB) into the boot sector, as GRUB was likely overwritten when you reinstalled Windows. There certainly should be questions here about that, either here on [su] or on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Windows installer overwrites GRUB and you have to reinstall it. Make a live USB or CD you can use for the recovery.

1. Boot from the live CD/USB and open a terminal
2. Type 'sudo fdisk -l' and you will see devices like sda/sdb and a number. These are your hard drives and the pendrive is listed here too, and the numbers are your partitions. Find the hard drive you installed your system on.
3. Type 'sudo grub-install ', where the device is which you found in the previous step. For example, you installed on /dev/sda then you type 'sudo grub-install /dev/sda'. Notice that there is no number after sda.
4. Type 'sudo update-grub' to make it scan the operating systems on your HD.

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

If U haven't installed Ubuntu on LVM partitions, then there is a simple way to recover grub from windows without any live CD.

Install [EasyBCD - Community Edition](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml) on Windows 7. Open the program. On the left side, click "Add New Entry", then under Operating Systems menu, select "Linux/BSD". Then under Type, select "Grub 2". Use some name in Name field. Then under Device, select "Autodetect and load." Then click "Add Entry".

Now reboot system and select the entry u created from boot menu. It detects ubuntu bootloader and loads it. Now boot into Ubuntu and perform some commands to reinstall grub.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

assuming u have only one hard disk.

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot. U get the previous grub bootloader. Once u see that boot into windows and remove the windows bootloader entry u have created from Easy BCD.

Thats it.

If u ever wanted to access linux ext partitions on windows, u will need to install ext file system driver on windows.
[Ext2 File System Driver for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/)